# Commit amend and force push to a shallow git clone

Tags: git, continuous-integration

I have a CI which clones a big repo, where each commit is large, adds another commit, and pushes the changes. To save disk space, I want to change it to amend the last commit and force push (with lease).

I tried the following:

```bash
git clone --depth 1
# make changes...
git add .
git commit --amend -m "changes"
git push --force-with-lease
```

This causes all history to be wiped. Since I have only a single commit in my shallow repo, the amended commit has no parent.

Using `--depth 2` fixes it, bit it causes to fetch one additional large commit. Is there another option to fetch only one commit, amend it and push the changes while preserving the rest of the remote history?